# what is paygate folder in magento core payment module?

Tags: payment, model

In core payment module models folder contain paygate folder.it contain two classes(`Mage/Payment/Model/Paygate`).`Request.php` and `Result.php` and these two are empty.

So my doubts are

1. Whether these two classes are related to overall payment functionality or particular 3rd party functionality?
2. If it is 3rd party functionality, then why they are appearing in payment module?
3. `Request.php` class name is
   `Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet_Request`.
   As you can see, its not following convention.How is it possible ?
4. Can any one explain what is the use of these?

Comment: paygate is payment module in magento, where you found only 2 classes.

Comment: app/code/core/mage/payment/model/paygate/

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Comment: I guess it may be by mistake addded this two classes under payment module in magento. As it's class are like: Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet_Request which is wrong.

Comment: for magento 1.8 & magento 1.9 same they are giving.I observed before only what you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my opinion.
Nothing mind-blowing. As you suspected those classes are never used.
I say that because every class except `Mage_Core_Model_App` is instantiated using `getModel` or any other factory method.  And for those methods to work, you have to follow the class naming conventions (file path matches class name) or declare the rewrite class in `config.xml`.

Also there is an other class `Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet_Request` located in the right place `app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet/Request.php`.
I guess that if the class you mention is ever instantiated you will get an error saying that you cannot redeclare the class.

I guess this is just a slip-up from the core team. Somone copied the file in there and forgot about it.

As a side note: that class has been there at least since version 1.1.

The model `Request` (the one from the correct path) are used to send the request to authorize.net.
See `Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet::_getRequest`. They could have easily use a `Varien_Object` for this, but I guess someone thought that some additional methods could be created in this class and decided to have it as a separate class.
I didn't find any use of `Response`.

Comment: thanks Marius.Can you explain 4th point(use of Request.php and Result.php in Paygate module).

Comment: @sivakumar. See my update. But keep in mind it is only an opinion. I don't know for sure.